# How do I prevent captured image from delaying when navigated to another page?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate a captured image from camera to another page. these are the steps I used

First I store the captured image in an async storage then navigate to the new page I want to display that image. From there I get back the saved image or images in the async storage.

***The problem is that:**
The first image taken with the camera and navigated to the next page doesn't appear,
It appears on the second time I take another picture.
The images displayed on the display page delays by an image.*

**Tried using await on the async storage set item so that navigation will only occur when the captured image has been saved, but that doesn't work for me.**

from the console seems navigation occurs before the image is saved asynchronously hence the delay in one image.

Any help on this?

this is the code sample in the camera functional component that saves the captured image before navigating

```
const saveImage = async(res) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('photos').then((photos) => {
        const photo = photos ? JSON.parse(photos) : [];
        photo.push(res);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('photos', JSON.stringify(photo));
        console.log("ASYNC STORAGE WORKED : "+JSON.parse(photos)  )
        //true if transferred image from camera is pushed to array
    return () =>{
    photo.clear();  
    }

    }); 
}
```

the code in the camera functional component that navigates to the next page

```
<Pressable
              
               onPressIn={()=>{
                    takePicture(); 
                }
              }
               onPressOut={()=>{
                navigation.navigate('EvidenceSubmission')
                }
               }
               
               style={styles.capture}>

               <Icon
                   name="camera"
                   size={28}
                   color="#1D5179"/>
            </Pressable>
```

the page that displays the image

```
useEffect(()=> {
       
        /*Get the stored captured images from async storage*/   
        async () => {
            try {
                const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('photos')
                if(value !== null){
                    setPhotos((JSON.parse(value)).reverse())
                    setIsLoading(false);    
                }
            }catch(e){
            console.log('error with async getData');
            }  
        }

        return ()=> {
           
        }
    
    }, []);
```

Comment: What module are you using for taking the picture?

Comment: am using "react-native-camera":

Comment: Why are you manually doing something, what module does for you? You don't need to store image in Async storage. After taking the picture, you get Image source, which you can use everywhere in your app.

Comment: I am retrieving the image one after the order on camera capture to another page to form a gallery view. user is able to go back to the camera to take another picture. How do i implement this with async storage? -Vladimír